# NetSuite SuiteScript 2.0 invalid_fld_value when setting sublist field value

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I'm using the NetSuite Contracts Renewals module and trying to make a  NetSuite User Event script (SuiteScript 2.0) that sets a custom field value on the Contract Item record based on the original sales order.

The script works fine when I edit/save the record manually but when I use the "Create Contract Item" button on the Contract record I get the following error:

`INVALID_FLD_VALUE  You have entered an Invalid Field Value 8.0 for the following field: custrecord_count`

The field is definitely an Integer field and it makes no sense that it would work in one context but not the other.  I even tried hardcoding a value but no dice.

Anyone have any ideas?

Here's an example to illustrate how I'm attempting to set the value:

```
var contractItemRecord = context.newRecord;
contractItemRecord.setValue({
    fieldId: 'custrecord_count',
    value: 8
});
```

Answer (score 4):

SS2.0 is inconsistent in its type handling. Sometimes it works with the types as expected and sometimes it needs a string but does a poorer job of type coercion than SS1.0.

I'd try `count.toString()` or `count.toFixed(0)`